# Suppressing the 'Appendices' page

Tags: formatting, appendices

My book has a single appendix chapter called 'Mathematical Appendix'. I'm using the appendix package. How do I get rid of the 'Appendices' page?

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,openany]{book}
\usepackage{appendix}
\renewcommand\appendixtocname{Mathematical Appendix}

\begin{document} 
\frontmatter 
\tableofcontents 
\mainmatter

\chapter{The first chapter}
Bla bla

\appendix
\appendixpage
\addappheadtotoc
\chapter*{Mathematical Appendix}
\renewcommand\thesection{A.\arabic{section}}
Bla bla
\section{Functions}
Bla bla

\end{document}
```

Comment: Remove the line `\appendixpage`

Comment: The solution is apparent after reading the »[appendix](http://texdoc.net/pkg/appendix)« manual.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Delete the command `\appendixpage`.

Answer (score 8):

For the benefit of others who may have this problem but *not* have `\appendixpage` anywhere in their code, there are (at least?) two ways the Appendix page can be enabled:

1. Via the `\appendixpage` command, as mentioned above.

   - Remove this line from your code and the Appendix page will disappear.
2. The `page` option of the `appendix` package.

   - `\usepackage[page]{appendix}` WILL include the Appendix page.
   - `\usepackage{appendix}` will NOT include the Appendix page.

Answer (score 4):

The fact that you have to remove the line

```
\appendixpage
```

is already stated in Ian's answer.

There is also an error in your code. If you want the appendix "Mathematical Appendix" not to be numbered, but you want it to appear in the ToC, you have to issue the command

```
\addappheadtotoc
```

just after the line

```
\chapter*{Mathematical Appendix}
```

and not before it, otherwise you get a wrong page number in the ToC.

This is how your MWE should be changed:

```
\documentclass[12pt,openany]{book}
\usepackage{appendix}
\renewcommand\appendixtocname{Mathematical Appendix}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter

\chapter{The first chapter}
Bla bla

\appendix

\chapter*{Mathematical Appendix}
\addappheadtotoc
\renewcommand\thesection{A.\arabic{section}}
Bla bla
\section{Functions}
Bla bla

\end{document}
```

Output (ToC):

[image]